# Review product list 2 colums left

Tags: layout, template, xml, review

I want to set the review product list as a 2 column left template.

I currently use this in my review.xml file:

```
<review_product_list translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product Reviews List</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
<reference name="content">
</reference>
</review_product_list>
```

But that does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please clear cache

Comment: @AmitBera I did clean the cache, but it still does not work.

Comment: have you local.xml at app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/layout

Comment: Yes I did set it correctly on that page.

Comment: here you need check review_product_lis handler and set template  from here

Comment: @AmitBera I did set it on in that review.xml file, just with the code displayed above.

Comment: have you check review_product_list exits in local.xml

Comment: @AmitBera Stupid, that is where it set incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: cannot understand

Comment: @AmitBera I did set the template to 2colums-left. Where can I define the left column? So where can I define what content should be displayed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `local.xml` at your layout folder then `the priority  of this file is maximum.`

If you set the template from this file for `review_product_list` handler then   you was set from `review.xml` then `review.xml`  code don't works.